# Update CKEditor's CSS via JavaScript after instance is already created

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I create a CKEditor instance like this:

```
include 'ckeditor/ckeditor.php';
$CKeditor = new CKeditor();
$CKeditor->basePath = './ckeditor/';
$config = array();
echo '<textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea>';
$config['contentsCss'] = 'style1.css';
$config['ImageUpload'] = false;
$config['toolbar'] = 'Basic';
$events = array();
$CKeditor->replace('content', $config, $events);
```

Now I would like to change some configuration details (e.g. "contentsCss") via JavaScript when this instance has already been created. Is this possible?

My idea was this (which doesn't work, unfortunately):

```
<a href="#" onclick="CKEDITOR.instances.content.config.toolbar = 'Full'; return false;">change toolbar style</a>
```

Comment: Replacing the style sheet "live" using JavaScript *may* be possible somehow but it may turn out to be very difficult and/or shaky. Is it not an option to simply reload the editor with the new settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried a lot of different things and ended up with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateCKEditor() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.content;
    if (editor) {
        editor.destroy(true);
    }
    var newConfig = { skin : XYZ, toolbar : 'Basic', contentsCss : '' };
    CKEDITOR.replace('content', newConfig);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.yourEditorsId.window.$.document.getElementsByTagName("link")[0].href = 'new/path/style.css';
```

Where yourEditorsId is, you guessed it, the ID of your editor, and 0 is the index of your stylesheet.

Comment: It has a window property on your editor instance, which is a wrapper around the real window object. It adds some convenience methods for window.